# How to get last redirected url in php

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I had used this code to get redirected url in $last_url string :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.djgol.com/files/download/id/163799"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
$last_url= curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

$output = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $last_url;
curl_close($ch); 


?>
```

but i am unable to get redirected url ,, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the URL before starting the request. Try moving the `$last_url= curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` line to after the `curl_exec($ch);` call.

Answer (score 0):

use 
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`
to get last url. I use this only.

Comment: will please give me full coding of this script..means where to add this

Comment: <?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.djgol.com/files/download/id/163799"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
$last_url= curl_getinfo($ch,$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

$output = curl_exec($ch); 

 

echo $last_url;
curl_close($ch);
?>

Comment: I don't know curl, so only I can't give the full code@user3488401, but thanks to @user3488401